# The hidden propety of file is useless

Tags: autodesk-forge

I use "GET content" to get content of a folder,with no filter. But files which were deleted are returned, and their "hidden" properties are false.

Comment: About the "GET content", did you mean this API[GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/)?

Comment: May I know where did you delete those files, `Plans` or `Project Files`, and what the detial procedure to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes,  I used that api. And i deleted files in the folder which I created in Plans.The name of Plans folder was also changed,it became an chinese name.@EasonKang

Comment: May I ask you a favor to call GET Folder Contents API with the `includeHidden` filter in both folders of `Plans` and `Project Files` to check if deleted files are still shown? e.g. `projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents?includeHidden=false`

Comment: And here is a blog explaining the deleting files behavior of the Docs: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-get-deleted-files-oss-bucket-and-saas-cloud-products

Comment: I tried as what you said. The ret of Plans folder is still wrong,but the ret of Project Files is right, even without the filter.And, I deleted files by docs itself, instead of forge.@EasonKang

Comment: This might be an issue of the Docs. Since I need some private information from you, could you please send a request to `forge.help@autodesk.com` and assign to me?

Comment: I have sent a request,But I don't konw how to assign to you...

Comment: It's just fine to mention my name in the mail. However, I catch you, our postman should on his way to your mail box~ :)